# How do I enable a user account I sudo-ed into to play audio?

Tags: linux, sudo, pulse-audio

So I login to another's user account using the following command:

> sudo -u  bash

I  use the following command to test sound from that account:

> [winejail@localhost ~]$ play test.mp3

I get the errors listed below:

> ALSA lib pulse.c:242:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect:
> Connection refused
>
> play FAIL ao: startwrite [ao driver]: Corrupted encoding data (bits
> per sample should not be zero) play FAIL sox: Sorry, there is no
> default audio device configured

How do I share audio access ?
I read in a few places that pulseaudio runs a seperate instance per X user.